# Adding View dynamically and setting Parameters and rules is not working properly (android)

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, view

i'm facing a problem in my android project . Here I have a **imageButton** , on click of this I have to inflate a layout file and dynamically add it inside a Relative layout . adding view is working perfectly . but the problem is after adding this child view I need move the image button below the new child layout . but my **imageButton** is inflating under the child view , maybe I'm missing some LayoutParameters and rules .

here are my code

```
private void addDestinationViews() {

    View destinationChildView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.destination_city_item, null);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.add_destinationbutton);
    destinationChildView.setLayoutParams(params);

    mInflated_view_holder.addView(destinationChildView);
}
```

here is the layout i want to inflate

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/add_destination_button_back"
    android:text="afaf"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="start|center"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cancle_destination_imagebutton"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cross_place_icon"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

this is the relative layout which will host the inflated layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inflated_view_holder_three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/child_counter_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_destinationbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_place_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_destination_button_back"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**P.S** I forget to mention this child view will be added upon the imageButton press . so the code needs to be dynamic here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to host your inflated layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/inflated_view_holder_three"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_destinationbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/inflated_view_holder_three"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <!--android:background="@drawable/add_destination_button_back"-->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know in case of any issues

Comment: thnks man , you save me . but other thing I have mentioned earlier is not working . like after inflating the first view if the user press the image button new view needs to inflated upon the oder one . may be need some layout parameters and layout rules runtime , but I have no idea what it should be. @Sandy